# echo codeigniter count function in view

Tags: codeigniter-3

Guys I'm having hard time to echo from my model

```
Function total_count {
    $this->db->select('user_id, COUNT(user_id) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('user_id'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $query = $this->db->get('tablename', 10);
```

Return $query->result();
    }

In my controller I pass it through data

```
$data = array (
'totalcount' => $this->mymodel->total_count(),
);
```

In view

```
Echo $totalcount
```

Comment: Please try to var_dump($totalcount) to see what is in your result set as this is a result set not a value according to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are returning something from your model's total_count function ... as per your listing there is no return statement which means null will be echoed resulting in blank.

Just selecting will not make the model returns the query result, you need to return explicitly

Please try to `var_dump($totalcount)` to see what is in your result set as this is a result set not a value according to your query.

Comment: Dumping the variable works and generate arrays with total however in view it's not working as vardump

Comment: As @evanXG pointed out, you have to write `return $query;` at the end of the model's `total_count()` method.

Comment: ok then the problem might be the data your are sending along to the view load statement . please make sure the key is not being overridden by another variable in your view. to test please change the key in your data array data['mytotal']=$queryResult() and try again